# Maximum allowed Price limit in Android In-App Purchase for a digital product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I know, It is not a proper programming related question but i will only get the answers over here.

Can anyone please tell me the maximum allowed price for an android in-app purchase?
or must i say maximum price limit for a digital good in android app?

and any documentation will also help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Max price has been increased to $400 USD as of Oct 2015.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286

Answer (score 1):

It depends by the currency of the user.

These are the ranges for the most important currencies:

```
Currency     Min         Max
USD          .99      200.00
EUR          .50      199.00
GBP          .50      150.00
CHF          .99      200.00
AUD          .99      200.00
CAD          .99      210.00
JPY        99.00   20,000.00
```

You can find the complete list here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286

Comment: Do you know of a json endpoint for these limits?